# WPF Combobox Dropdown and MouseDown

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, windows-10

I have a Popup and a Window.
There are some comboboxes on the Popup.

I drop down the combobox and while the combo box is still dropped down I click on the Window, But

Mouse event response is on Popup, and drop-down box is not closed.

How to make the mouse-down respond on the window or close the drop-down box?

Answer (score 0):

add `Window_MouseDown` event to `window` then close your `Combobox`

```
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    myCombobox.IsDropDownOpen = false;
}
```